# Couldn't find Competition with 'id'= (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, parameters

I'm working a web app that uses Ruby on Rails. I've read about some of the "Couldn't find *** with 'id'= (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)" posts but none of them solve my problem.

I have a HAML view that takes the competitions_id parameter and passes it along.

```
= form_tag weigh_ins_path, :method => :post, :id => 'select_weigh_in_form' do

  = label :weigh_in, :competition_id, 'Competition'
  = select :weigh_in, :competition_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@competitions, 'id', 'name'), :include_blank => true

  = submit_tag 'Select Competition & Week'
```

I have a request with the following parameters, including competitions_id which isn't nil or null or anything like that:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"***Some stuff***==",
 "weigh_in"=>{"competition_id"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Select Competition & Week"}
```

I have a controller that expects the competition_id parameter:

```
  def create
    @competition = Competition.find params[:competition_id]
  ***some more stuff**
```

But, I get this error when I test with Cucumber:

```
And I press "Select Competition & Week"                                      
  Couldn't find Competition with 'id'= (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

And I get this error when I try to use the web app:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WeighInsController#create
Couldn't find Competition with 'id'=
```

So even though the POST request from the view is sending a parameter, the controller isn't getting it? How can I fix or troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `competition_id` is nested in the request you posted in your question.  Try retrieving it from params like this:

```
params[:weigh_in][:competition_id]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it was nested because I didn't intend to design it that way.